# php escaping user input to display in html

Tags: php, html, escaping, html-parsing, user-input

php page1 --> below bit is pure html:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
-----------submit button, end form --etc.--------------
```

php page2 (and yes i have intended to stuff the text input from page1 into a hidden input in page2):

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$value) 
{
     $value = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes($value))); //attempt to cleanse the data before displaying
}
echo "<p><input type='hidden' id='name' name='name' value='".$_REQUEST['name']."'/>".$_REQUEST['name']."</p>";
```

The problem is that the output on page 2 is not producing w3 compliant html if the user enters input with quotes such as John O'Brien, the html becomes:

```
<p><input type='hidden' id='email' name='email' value='John O'Brien'/>John O'Brien</p>
```

I would also like to be able to produce w3 compliant html for any bad input data such as: j'o/h\n s"m,ith

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Surround attribute values with double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`. Then all you need is `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- First of all, not your code, nor any of ones posted above will ever work. For the very silly reason.
- Next, I am kinda fixated on preserving user input exactly as is. Why delete something might be important?
- Third, hidden values should be urlencoded I believe, rather than htmlencoded

so

```
$FORM = array();
foreach($_POST as $key =>$value) {
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    $FORM[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES);
}
echo "<p><input type='hidden' id='name' name='name' value='".$FORM['name']."'/>".
          $FORM['name'].
     "</p>";
```

Comment: awesome this is a correct solution, this was what i was after!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ENT_QUOTES` option to `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
$value = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes($value)), ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_REQUEST as &$value) 
{
     $value = addslashes(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($value)));
}
echo "<p><input type='hidden' id='name' name='name' value='".$_REQUEST['name']."'/>".$_REQUEST['name']."</p>";
```

Comment: For my information, is that valid HTML to use backslash-escaped quotes in attributes?  It renders in Chrome, but I don't think I've ever seen that before.

Comment: It's Valid ! I'm Tested it in all browsers

Comment: This code won't work… The value of the `$value` variable will only be set inside for `foreach` loop, and won't change in the original `$_REQUEST` array (as is the apparent intent). It would be possible to make the code work by passing `$value` as a reference, or by explicitly setting `$_REQUEST[$key] = …`. However, this is just bad form… Modifying the entire `$_REQUEST` array when it might be used by later code is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't use `$_REQUEST` - the book [Essential PHP Security by Chris Shifflet](http://phpsecurity.org/) suggests that this could make your application vulnerable to [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Next, depending on server configuration, you may not *have* to call `stripslashes(...)` - see the [`magic_quotes_gc` ini configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc). I'd use the [`get_magic_quotes_gpc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) to determine if it is necessary.

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$value) {
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
     $value = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($value));
}
echo "<p><input type='hidden' id='name' name='name' value='".$_REQUEST['name']."'/>".$_REQUEST['name']."</p>";
```

Comment: errrr... what's the point in adding slashes right after you stripped it out?